# S3 wget from EC2 instance gives 403 forbidden error despite all policies implemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Please help!

```
Last login: Wed Jul 23 00:04:41 2014 from 46.7.181.81 Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. ubuntu@ip:~$ wget https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hadoopconfigfiles/core-site.xml
--2014-07-23 00:29:12--   Resolving s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)...  Connecting to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)| connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2014-07-23 00:29:12 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I have tried everything. Policy from IAM, bucket policy, made the file public. gave all the permissions but still i get the forbidden error. I am using ec2 t2.micro instance and from command line i am using wget to get the file from my s3 bucket.

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hadoopconfigfiles/core-site.xml

this is the bucket policy i used

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1406073673060",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1406073666892",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::hadoopconfigfiles/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is the IAM policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

attached the IAM policy to instance as well and restarted but no effect. Please help.

BR,
Sarfraz.

Answer (score 0):

You bucket policy looks correct, so I would advise you to look at your CORS configuration and have it look somthing like this:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```